# Exporting multiple vectors to file from Matlab

Tags: matlab

I would like to store multiple vector/array matlab variables in a file so that i can reuse or plot the data (each vector) later. Every vector should represent a row. Vector elements ->columns, Vectors -> rows.

Can you advise me on the best approach to do that (mat file, csv, excel).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Every vector should represent a row. Vector elements ->columns, Vectors -> rows.

I'm not sure what you mean by that without any further  context. Anyway, saving variables for later use is easy enough. Here's a little demo:

```
 >> x = 1:5
 x =
      1     2     3     4     5
 >> y = 5:-1:1 
 y =
      5     4     3     2     1
 >> whos
   Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

   x         1x5                40  double              
   y         1x5                40  double              

 >> save('myvars')
 >> clear
 >> whos
 >> x
 Undefined function or variable 'x'. 
 >> y
 Undefined function or variable 'y'. 
 >> load('myvars')
 >> whos
   Name      Size            Bytes  Class     Attributes

   x         1x5                40  double              
   y         1x5                40  double              

 >> x
 x =
      1     2     3     4     5
 >> y
 y =
      5     4     3     2     1
```

This will create a file `myvars.mat` which holds the values of all currently defined variables.

EDIT in response to your comment:

So let's say we have these N vectors V1,V2,...VN, you can create the desired matrix by issueing

```
M = [V1;V2;...;VN]
```

Now save it to a file with

```
save('mymatrix', 'M')
```

This will create a file `mymatrix.mat` which holds the matrix `M` for later use. To load it into the workspace, simply issue

```
load('mymatrix')
```

Comment: I have multiple vectors V1,V2...Vn, they all need to be stored in a file. Like a matrix which rows are those vectors.

Comment: @user2703038 I've added example code for doing that in my answer.

Comment: Thank you! Is there an easy way to iterate thru the vectors and plot them from .mat?

Comment: for i = 1:size(M,1) figure; plot(M(i,:)); end